# Does anyone recognize this jQuery website plugin?

Tags: javascript, websites, plugin

I am working on a site that was made years ago (not be me) and I need to identify a jQuery file manager plugin. This plugin shows a file manager view in a browser and allows the user to visually navigate a directory tree and view, upload, or download files.

In its code it refers to itself as `documentLibrary` or `Document Library`. Based on file dates, it looks like this may have been implemented circa 2017.

I have tried a variety of Google searches, as you can imagine the terms "jQuery file manager" and "jQuery document library" yield a lot of results that have nothing to do with what I am looking for. I have tried searching for pieces of the code, but I do not have any luck.

I have found similarly named products related to a WordPress plugin and Sharepoint services, but they do not seem to be related to the plugin I am looking at.

Here are some snippets that seem like they could be identifiable by someone familiar with this plugin.

```
    $.documentLibrary = function(element, options) {
        
        var defaults = {
            ajax_url        : false,
            csrf            : false,
            file_container  : false,
            folder_table    : false,
            tool_bar        : false,
            drop_zone       : false,
            is_media_modal  : false,
            example_callback: function() {},
            restrict_files : []
        };
```

```
        plugin.init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            plugin.open_folders = [];
            if(plugin.settings.csrf===false){throw "Configuation Error: The document library requires a csrf token for ajax calls.";}
            if(plugin.settings.ajax_url===false){throw "Document Library requires an ajax url.";}
            if(plugin.settings.folder_table === false ){
                throw "Document Library requires a file holder.";
```

Thanks for any help. Let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: Jquery or general webdev site might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will check!